# Visual MDI Tabs part of which class

Tags: visual-c++

I habe a Visual MFC MultiDoc application. I want to get an `ON_WM_RBUTTONDOWN` message if I click on the tab. I assumed that this part of the `CMDIChildWndEx` class. But I don't get any message if I click the tab. So I guess it must be another class.

[image]

Comment: The main frame window (if it is derived from `CMDIFrameWndEx`) will 'own' the tab control, which is a `CMFCTabCtrl`. A reference to this is returned by the [GetMDITabs()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmdiframewndex-class?view=vs-2019#getmditabs) member function.

Comment: @Adrian, if I want to implement an `ON_WM_RBUTTODOWN` message, do I have to create a derived class from `CMFCTabCtrl` to get this message?

Comment: I would presume so - but I have never attempted such a task, which is why I didn't post an answer. It's likely to be a bit tricky. Good luck.

Comment: And I guess you will need to override the `CMDIFrameWndEx` create process to make a tab control of your derived class, rather than the default base class. Poking around the MFC source code may give you some help.

Comment: @Adrian, `GetMDITabs()` is not working. The number of tabs is 0 and therefore no active existing tab exist. But it is atleast on tab available.
I call this methode from `CMainFrm`. What could be wrong?

Comment: @Adrian, `GetMDITabs()` doesn't work with `MDITabGroups`. First it is neccessary to get the active child `GetRelatedTabGroup()`. If it `IsTabbedMDIChild()` you can use `GetRelatedTabGroup` to get a pointer to `CMFCTabCtrl`.
Is there any documentation which describes the differences?